# What is the angular velocity defined by Slerp(q1(t), q2(t), s(t))?

Tags: lie-groups, quaternions, orientation

I wanna get the angular velocity of the rotation q(t) defined by Slerp(q1(t), q2(t), s(t)), where q stands for quaternion and Slerp is the spherical linear interpolation. Both q1 and q2 is time varying. So how could I get the derivative of the Slerp and the corresponding angular velocity?

Comment: How do you define angular velocity for a path on the three-sphere?

Comment: The angular velocity is a 3D vector omega expressed in the same frame where the rotation is expressed.